# Pandas: problem accessing data by index label

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

Looking at various ways to look up values in a small reference DataFrame.
Converted one column to an index hoping to be able to use text labels (all values are unique) to query data using "loc". But something is wrong. What am I missing? Thanks in advance.

Looking at Pandas documentation, it seems to me the above should work?
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html#pandas.DataFrame.loc

```
data = {'country':['france', 'sweden', 'usa', 'japan'],
        'currency':['eur','sek','usd','jpy'],
        'forex':[2,3,4,5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

```
df.set_index('country')

    currency    forex
country     
france  eur 2
sweden  sek 3
usa usd 4
japan   jpy 5
```

```
# this works
df[df.country == 'usa'].forex
2    4
Name: forex, dtype: int64
```

```
# this works
df.iloc[2].forex
4
```

```
# this does not work
df.loc['usa'].forex
```

```
KeyError: 'usa'
```

Comment: pls use "df.set_index('country', inplace=True)", instead of "df.set_index('country')"

Comment: Works for me if you use the inplace option or `df = df.set_index('country')`

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks Ömer, that solved it.